# Strange issue regarding my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, my.cnf

I'm getting a weird message from `phpmyadmin` saying:

`#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`

What I found online is that I should increase the size of `max_allowed_packet` witch should be in the `my.conf` file witch is located at `/etc/my.cnf`. Untill now everything is fine, but the problem is that this file does not contain what I need.

Here is the content of the .cnf file on my server:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Where should I look in order to increase the size of the packet? I'm new in the linux world and I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `my.cnf` file to include the single line under `[mysqld]` in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

now `restart the MySQL service` and you are done.

You can see its current value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can try changing it like this, but it's unlikely this will work on shared hosting:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

Also please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set the limit to (for example) 8M

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=8M
```

Comment: I already tried it, Then I restarted MySQL, nothing happened. I restarted the whole server, but the issue remains :(

Comment: That's because setting server variables with SET GLOBAL doesn't persist on MySQL restart. You can use it to set a variable without restarting MySQL, but to make it persist you have to put in my.cnf as well.